# Schliemann's method of programming language learning

Tags: c++, perl, programming-languages, lisp

**Background**: 19th-century German archeologist Heinrich Schliemann was of course famous for his successful quest to find and excavate the city of Troy (an actual archeological site for the Troy of Homer's Iliad).

However, he is just as famous for being an [astonishing learner of languages](http://www.language-learning-tips.com/17_Schliemanns_method.htm) - within the space of two years, he taught himself fluent Dutch, English, French, Spanish, Italian and Portuguese, and later went on to learn seven more, including both modern and ancient Greek.

One of the methods he famously used was comparison of a known text, e.g. take a book in a language one is fluent in, take a good translation of a book in a language you wish to learn, and go over them in parallel. (various sources cited the book used by Schliemann to be the Bible, or, as the link above states, a novel).

Now, for the actual question.

**Has anyone used (or heard of) an equivalent of Schliemann's method for learning a new programming language?** E.g. instead of basing the leaning on references and tutorials, take a somewhat comprehensive set of programs known to have high-quality code in both languages implementing similar/identical algorithms and learn by comparing them?

I'm curious about either personal experiences of applying such an approach, or references to something published, or existance of codebases which could be used for such an approach?

What got me thinking about the idea was [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=50) and some code snippets I saw on SO, in C++, Perl and Lisp.

Comment: Interesting question... I could see this strategy being very useful, given some definition of fluency and a set of paradigms (like, maybe all procedural, object oriented languages).  Project Euler solutions would make for excellent source text, as well!

Comment: @robert Project Euler solutions tend only to be applicable to PE type problems - the real world is quite different.

Comment: @Neil - but the goal is to learn how language X works based on seing comparisons with language Y - I don't think PE problems are a very bad domain for that, although admittedly not 100% the best possible

Comment: @DVK If my problem is how to write a multi-threaded server to perform real-time trading against an international electronic stock exchange, it's hard to see how PE-type solutions are applicable. Toy problems - toy solutions

Comment: @Neil - but the goal is to learn the new language, NOT to learn to write real-time trading system. To put it in Schliemann's terms, you want to read books/documents in a target language, NOT write award-winning books.

Comment: @DVK So you only want to read code, not to write it? That isn't obvious from your question. The only point in learning a programming language is to do something useful (and I exclude artificial problems like those posed by PE here) with it.

Comment: @Neil - I want to learn the language. Which starts off with a level of proficiency necessary to read code or write simpler tasks. I am not aware of a learning technique which requires one two write a web server or a trading system as a first task for learning a language :)

Comment: @DVK When I learned C (many years ago), the first program I wrote after "hello world" was to write APL source code to a dot-matrix printer. IMHO, you cannot really learn a language by writing trivial programs. I realise I may be in a minority in this.

Comment: I agree with "really learn the language" part - but you seem to avoid the middle ground wich is "become familiar with the language" which is somewhat above the level of hello world :)

Comment: Visual Studio typically states every tutorial example in both VB.NET and C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Main_Page) may be useful. To quote the site:-

> Rosetta Code is a programming chrestomathy site. The idea is to present solutions to the same task in as many different languages as possible, to demonstrate how languages are similar and different, and to aid a person with a grounding in one approach to a problem in learning another. Rosetta Code currently has 372 tasks, and covers 197 languages, though we do not (and cannot) have solutions to every task in every language.

Answer (score 9):

I would expect Schliemann's method to work very poorly, because one of the points of creating a new programming language is to introduce *new objects of discourse* and *new means of transferring control*.  In Schliemann's method of comparing two texts, the objects of discourse are always the same, only the language used to talk about them is different.

- For example, method dispatch and inheritance are inherently new things.  So maybe if you know Simula-67 you can learn Java, and maybe even you can stretch to learn Smalltalk or C++.
  But you can't possibly learn Tcl or Scheme or ML or Diesel because single inheritance and dynamic dispatch just aren't there.
- Similarly, if you've only ever seen C or C++, or maybe even Pascal/Ada/Modula/Clu, nothing can really prepare you for the power and expressiveness of first-class functions.
- As another example, how you can you compare solutions to string-processing problems if one language (Perl) has regular expressions, a second (SNOBOL) has pattern matching, and a third (Icon) has string scanning?  Your poor head will explode!

Schliemann's method may have its uses if the languages in question are very similar.  Say you know Java and you want to learn C#, or vice versa.  Or change between languages in the OCaml/F#/SML family.  But in most cases I suspect Schliemann's method will do you more harm than good.

Answer (score 3):

It's unlikely that the best way of implementing something in one language follows the same pattern in another. It's therefore very difficult to find points of correspondence. Taking this approach is likely to teach you how to program badly in the language you are learning - look at all the bad, Java-like code written in C++ by people with Java as a first programming language.

**Edit:** Typical java in C++ code:

```
string * s = new string;
```

instead of the C++ way:

```
string s;
```

Comment: Neil - I know conceptually what you're talking about (from seing C++ written in Perl), but I'd be curious what a typical "Java written in C++" looks like if you have an example handly

Comment: that is actually some of the cleanest C++ I have ever seen.

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages are less about syntax and more about idioms. I really doubt you could do a side by side comparison of say Apache source in C and YAWS in Erlang and actually learn either one of the languages in either direction. Say you know C what do you do when the language you are learning has single assignment variables, or no ternary operator. There very few 1:1 mappings even among impendence matched languages like OO languages. I mean C++ doesn't map 1:1 to Java or Python and they are all OO in nature.

Comment: That is correct - but you can see, for a simple example, a loop-y and recursive implementations of a factorial, and then see a map/reduce approach to the same in perl - which will teach you nothing about factorioals but LOADS about how things should be done in Perl (e.g. map/reduce approach)

Comment: Basically, I was thinking slightly (or significantly) smaller elements being compared than a full web server

Comment: what Schliemann was doing was reverse engineering syntax and grammar. What is more important when learning a new programming language is the over arching idioms. Imagine trying to learn how to write Chinese poetry while only having the Chinese and English versions of the Tao te Ching [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching].  That is why it is important to compare larger corpus of code in total. You can't capture the personality or flavor of a language unless you look at a large piece of code, except Perl, even small pieces of Perl suck! :-)

Comment: And these days, Standard Libraries, "Batteries Included", etc. are more important than how to write a loop or a switch statement when there are things like list comprehensions built into languages and/or their standard libraries.